# Invoke `?:` using `send` in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Can I / how would I go about calling the ternary operator using the `send :name, *args, &blk` syntax construct? I don't have a practical reason to do this, but it came up.

Here you can see my woeful attempts:

```
i = 7

send "?:", proc { i > 2 }, true, false
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `?:' for main:Object

proc { i > 2 }.send "?:", true, false
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `?:' for #<Proc:0x00000001ef77b0@(irb):3>

proc { i > 2 }.call.send "?:", true, false
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `?:' for true:TrueClass
```

Comment: `? :` does not "bind" to a object, so `send` is less likely to work with it. Other similar syntaxes are `if / while / begin` etc.
In case that is needed in practice, we could use a a proxy object.

Comment: hello have you considered eval/instance_eval?

Comment: @Bohdan yes I suppose that is the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that. The ternary operator construction, or the `?` part of it, is not a method; as you noticed, it is a syntactic construct. Meanwhile, `send` can only handle methods.